# MIPS Assembly with MARS Compiler

Tags: mips, counting

We are going to implement a simple program with MIPS commands in the MARS simulator. Assumption
Suppose we have an array of 10 members. Implement the counting sort algorithm and with its help, average the data
find. How we can do that?

```
.data
    array: .word 2, 10, 6, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 10, 9
    n: .word 10
    max: .word 0
    count: .space 44  # (max + 1) * 4 bytes

.text
.globl main
main:
    # Initialize max to the first element of the array
    lw $t0, array($zero)
    sw $t0, max($zero)

    # Find the maximum element in the array
    li $t1, 1  # Initialize i = 1
    lw $t2, n($zero)
loop1:
    bge $t1, $t2, count_loop  # Exit loop when i >= n

    lw $t3, array($t1)
    lw $t4, max($zero)
    ble $t3, $t4, continue_loop1

    sw $t3, max($zero)
continue_loop1:
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1
    j loop1

count_loop:
    # Initialize count array elements to 0
    li $t1, 0  # Initialize i = 0
    li $t4, 0  # Initialize j = 0
    lw $t2, max($zero)
    addiu $t2, $t2, 1  # max + 1

count_loop_init:
    beq $t1, $t2, sort_loop  # Exit loop when i == (max + 1)

    sw $t4, count($t1)
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1
    j count_loop_init

sort_loop:
    li $t1, 0  # Initialize i = 0
    li $t4, 0  # Initialize j = 0
    lw $t2, n($zero)

sort_loop_init:
    bge $t1, $t2, exit  # Exit loop when i >= n

    lw $t3, array($t1)
    lw $t5, count($t3)
    beqz $t5, continue_sort_loop

    sw $t1, array($t4)
    addiu $t4, $t4, 4
    addiu $t5, $t5, -1
    sw $t5, count($t3)

continue_sort_loop:
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1
    j sort_loop_init

exit:
    # End of program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: How is the posted code related to your question?

Comment: Assembly code is assembled, not _compiled_, you use as assembler not a compiler.

Comment: Your comments seem to indicate that you have an algorithm you're following, using variables like `i` and `j`.  Having a working algorithm is a good place start.  Do you know that the algorithm works for sure?  If you have one, then post it as well.  Also ask a more specific question, something about MIPS, like maybe how to do some line or expression of C code in MIPS; that makes for a better question than how to do a homework problem.